# function raises error 'APPLY: argument list given to + is dotted'

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am currently trying to write a function that returns the average of list in decimal.

```lisp
(defun calc-list-average (lst)
    (float (/ (apply '+ lst) (length lst))))
```

When I call the function like this everything works fine:

```lisp
(defvar *a-lst* '(5 6 1 3 6 7))
(princ (calc-list-average *a-lst*))
```

However when I try to call the function with a list that has been dynamically generated I get the error 'argument list given to + is dotted (terminated by WUERFEL-ERGEBNIS)'

```lisp
(let ((wuerfel-seiten 6) (wuerfel-ergebnis ()))
    (loop
        (let ((menu-option (get-option)))
            (cond ((eql menu-option 1)
                    (princ "Bitte geben Sie die Anzahl der Wuerfelseiten ein: ")
                    (setq wuerfel-seiten (read)))
                  ((eql menu-option 2)
                    (princ "Bitte geben Sie die Anzahl der Wuerfelwuerfe ein: ")
                    (let ((wuerfel-wuerfe (read)))
                        (setq wuerfel-ergebnis (get-random-list wuerfel-seiten wuerfel-wuerfe))))
                  ((eql menu-option 3)
                    (write-line "Wuerfelauswertung")
                    (princ (calc-list-average 'wuerfel-ergebnis))) ; <-- error is raised here
                  ((eql menu-option 4)
                    (exit))))))
```

The function get-option just prints a menu to the console and returns whatever the user writes to console. get-random-list returns a list and is called with (cap number-of-elements).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `calc-list-average`, you're passing the *symbol* `wuerfel-ergebnis` (basically, the name of the variable) instead of the *value* of that symbol. Change the call to

```
(calc-list-average wuerfel-ergebnis)
```

That is, remove the quote before `wuerfel-ergebnis`. The quote means “don't evaluate what follows”. But you do want to evaluate the symbol `wuerfel-ergebnis` to get its value.

Here's the explanation for the error “argument list given to `+` is dotted”. The function `apply` expects a list. In Lisp, a list is either the empty list `()` (which can also be written `nil`) or a `cons` of the first element of the list and the rest of the list. For example `'(1 2 3)` is equivalent to `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 ())))`. In a proper list, when you follow the right-hand side of the `cons` calls, you eventually reach `()`. If you use `cons` differently, you can build an *improper list*, where the right-hand side of `cons` calls reaches something that isn't `()`. The syntactic sugar to build an improper list uses a dot before the trailing non-nil value: `(1 2 . "a")` is equivalent to `(cons 1 (cons 2 "a"))`. So “dotted list” is another name for “improper list”. A (non-nil) symbol like `wuerfel-ergebnis` is a special case of an improper list where you reach the end after going down 0 `cons` calls.